# What are extra advantage of using ES6 module instead of revealing module pattern?

Tags: javascript, closures, ecmascript-6

I am exploring ES6 `module` and trying to figure out what extra advantage we get using ES6 module instead of `closure` along with `module pattern`(MP).

For example
util.js in ES6.

```
   var util ={
         abc:function(){
        //function body
    },
    def:function(){
         // function body
    }
    export default utils;   // here export is exposing the entire object
}
```

util.js using closure & module pattern

```
var util = (function(){
       function _abc(){
         console.log("abc")
           // function body
       };
    function _def(){
         // function body
      }

  return{          // each of the function will be exposed
      abc:_abc,
      def:_def

}
}(util ||{}))
```

someFile.js in ES6

```
import {utils} from "path/to/file"
```

In someFile.js with closure & module pattern

```
util.abc() // Will log "abc"
```

Also I know es6 `module` allow us to rename `imports & exports` 
Like `export { a as abc}` .

With closure & module pattern we can give a name whatever we like inside return statement like return `{ a:_abc}`

My question:What extra benefit we can get by using es6 module instead of closure& MP.One i guess is reduction in lines of code.

Please excuse me if I have missed any basic difference

Comment: While I understand the point of your post, your question as it is asked right now is way too broad to be a good fit for SO. Please [edit] your question to something more focused.

Comment: @Kyll rightly said. Even I was struggling to find an appropriate title anyway I changed it. hope it will converge to my doubt

Comment: "What extra benefit we can get by using es6 module instead of closure" is still too broad IMHO. Can you focus on one technical issue instead of having such an open question?

Comment: Your ES6 module has a syntax error, `export` declarations must be top-level. Please indent your code properly.

Comment: No, you can't use `import {utils} from …`  for a default export.

Answer (score 8):

With `var util = (function(){ bla bla bla }(util || {}));` the global namespace is polluted, so that once you have used `import {utils} from "path/to/file"`, it will remain in global namespace, i.e. you'll be have `window.util` everywhere, even after the module has finished it's work and replace by some other module. Now consider you have 100s of modules and you do it in the same way, then imagine how dirty would the poor **window** become!

However if ES6 Module or CommonJS or even AMD is used, then

1. The global namespace is not polluted.
2. [ES6] You can use `export default something` to export a default value to use `import from "path/to/file"`
3. [ES6] You can export multiple things from ES6 Module, using `export["anotherthing"]`

Furthermore I would recommend you to read this [blog post](https://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/).